# Angular Formly : required validation doesn't work if used as model[field] instead of model.field

Tags: validation, requiredfieldvalidator, angular-formly

below is the failure jsbin, where conditional required validation is not working

https://jsbin.com/xenuzeripa/1/edit?js,output

if i remove the dot's form the field name and change them to as below, i can use these fields as model.field instead of model[field] and everything starts working

Employment_Information__c.Other_Income_Picklist__c --> Other_Income_Picklist__c
Employment_Information__c.Annual_Income__c  --> Annual_Income__c

not sure what's the issue

Comment: above jsbin is with model.field whereas below is the correct failure jsbin with model[field]
https://jsbin.com/loxome/edit?js,output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression has to be valid. It needs to appear as: `model['field']` (with the `field` as a string). Here's an updated version: https://jsbin.com/juharo/edit?js (the double `!!` is to make sure that the `required` attribute gets assigned a boolean, rather than the value of `model['field']`).